# getting tickers from interactive brokers using post requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests

Hi All for some reason interactive brokers don't make it easily accessible to get tickers from their site. I currently get them via their exchange pages using a normal request query. However, this is becoming a bit less reliable. I am trying to implement a imitation of their product search https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/trading/products-exchanges.php#/

However, i am having some problems getting it to work as i am newish to this sort of web scrapping.

This is my current code

```
url = "https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/IBSales/servlet/exchange?apiPath=getProductsByFilters"
payload = {"pageNumber":1,"pageSize":"100","sortField":"symbol","sortDirection":"ASC","product_country":["GB"],"product_symbol":"","new_product":"all","product_type":["STK"],"domain":"uk"}
headers ={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

However, it returns the following

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 400</title>
</head><body>
<h1>400</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

So clearly I am not doing it correctly. I was wondering if anyone could help me make this work.

Cheers.

Comment: maybe API needs some API_KEY  and you have to register on page to get this API_KEY.

Comment: I checked page in browser (Firefox, using DevTools) First: it sends JSON data - so you should use `data=json.dumps(payload)` with header `content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` or simpler `json=payload`. Seconds: it sends some `cookies` which can be important for server. Maybe you should use `requests.Session()` and first `GET` this page (to get cookies) and later `POST` your requests. Eventually you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply i managed to implement your changes to get the desired result :) Ill add a answer in due course

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to furas I managed to get my code working using the following code

```
url = "https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/IBSales/servlet/exchange?apiPath=getProductsByFilters"


session = requests.Session()
session.get("https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/IBSales/servlet/exchange?apiPath=getProductsByFilters")
payload = {
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "pageSize": "100",
    "sortField": "symbol",
    "sortDirection": "ASC",
    "product_country": ["GB"],
    "product_symbol": "",
    "new_product": "all",
    "product_type": ["STK"],
    "domain": "uk"
}

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
}


response = session.post("https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/IBSales/servlet/exchange?apiPath=getProductsByFilters", json=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```